# debug output is not correctly displayed

Tags: linux, shell, debugging, set, ksh

I have a script which in the very beginning is checking if an env var is set.
If it is set, then it defines a variable with the env var path, concatenated with something else; it redirects the error in above set path and next line is `set -vx`. After that it continue with some other commands.

I was trying to execute the script in debug mode but it outputs only the debug lines for the condition where the env var is set and the command which are executed if it is true (meaning the initialization of variable; the redirecting and the `set -vx`command).

The execution of the code after is not displayed.

I don't know if it is executed or not. Is it a debugging option setting or my script is just stopping?!

Can someone tell what can I do to see the entire debug output of the script?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that redirection (`exec 2 >> ....`) redirects also debut output in same location where the errors are sent.

After I commented the redirection, it works fine.